# How to apply function to pairs of columns with purrr?

Tags: r, purrr

I have the following dataframe resulting from a join with dplyr:

```
data_frame(id=1:4, a.x = c(1, NA, 3, 4), a.y = c(1, 2, 3, 4), b.x = c(NA, NA, 3, NA), b.y = c(2, 2, NA, 4)) 
# A tibble: 4 x 5
     id   a.x   a.y   b.x   b.y
  <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1     1    NA     2
2     2    NA     2    NA     2
3     3     3     3     3    NA
4     4     4     4    NA     4
```

And I would like to replace all the NAs in the columns ending with `.x` with the value from the columns ending with `.y`. Eventually, I would like to achieve this:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 5
     id   a.x   a.y   b.x   b.y
  <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1     1     2     2
2     2     2     2     2     2
3     3     3     3     3    NA
4     4     4     4     4     4
```

I tried with purrr something like this:

```
data_frame(id=1:4, a.x = c(1, NA, 3, 4), a.y = c(1, 2, 3, 4), b.x = c(NA, NA, 3, NA), b.y = c(2, 2, NA, 4)) %>%
  map2_dfr(.x = ends_with('.y'), .y = ends_with('.x'), ~ case_when(is.na(.x) ~ .y,
                                                                   TRUE ~ .x))
```

Which is wrong. The documentation is a bit confusing to me, I think the issue here is that .x expects a vector, but how can I pass a list of columns then?

Comment: You can get the result—albeit in a longer form—with some tidyr: `df %>% gather(var, val, -id) %>% separate(var, c('ab', 'xy')) %>% spread(xy, val) %>% mutate(x = coalesce(x, y))`. Reverse the reshaping with `%>% gather(xy, val, x:y) %>% unite(var, ab, xy, sep = '.') %>% spread(var, val)`, if you like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [tidyr](/questions/tagged/tidyr) solution. We can `gather` the columns, `separate` by `.`, `arrange` by columns, `fill` the value toward up, `unite` columns, and finally `spread` the data frame to the original structure.

```
library(tidyverse)

dat2 <- dat %>%
  gather(Column, Value, -id) %>%
  separate(Column, into = c("Col1", "Col2")) %>%
  arrange(id, Col1, Col2) %>%
  group_by(id, Col1) %>%
  fill(Value, .direction = "up") %>%
  unite(Column, Col1, Col2, sep = ".") %>%
  spread(Column, Value) %>%
  ungroup()
dat2
## A tibble: 4 x 5
#      id   a.x   a.y   b.x   b.y
# * <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1  1.00  1.00  2.00  2.00
# 2     2  2.00  2.00  2.00  2.00
# 3     3  3.00  3.00  3.00 NA   
# 4     4  4.00  4.00  4.00  4.00
```

Or if the order of the columns in the data frame is good, we can use the `transpose` function from the [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) package, but be careful that the column types may change after the process.

```
dat2 <- dat %>%
  data.table::transpose() %>%
  fill(everything(), .direction = 'up') %>%
  data.table::transpose() %>%
  setNames(names(dat))
dat2
#   id a.x a.y b.x b.y
# 1  1   1   1   2   2
# 2  2   2   2   2   2
# 3  3   3   3   3  NA
# 4  4   4   4   4   4
```

Or a solution using [purrr](/questions/tagged/purrr) to create subset that with column names `ends_with` "x" and "y" first, and then replace the original columns ends with "x".

```
dat_x <- dat %>% select(ends_with("x"))
dat_y <- dat %>% select(ends_with("y"))

dat[, grepl("x$", names(dat))] <- map2(dat_x, dat_y, ~ifelse(is.na(.x), .y, .x)) 
dat
# # A tibble: 4 x 5
#      id   a.x   a.y   b.x   b.y
#   <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1  1.00  1.00  2.00  2.00
# 2     2  2.00  2.00  2.00  2.00
# 3     3  3.00  3.00  3.00 NA   
# 4     4  4.00  4.00  4.00  4.00
```

**DATA**

```
dat <- data_frame(id=1:4, a.x = c(1, NA, 3, 4), a.y = c(1, 2, 3, 4), b.x = c(NA, NA, 3, NA), b.y = c(2, 2, NA, 4))
```